# Creating queue for Flask backend that can handle multiple users

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am creating a robot that has a Flask and React (running on raspberry pi zero) based interface for users to request it to perform tasks. When a user requests a task I want the backend to put it in a queue, and have the backend constantly looking at the queue and processing it on a one-by-one basis. Each tasks can take anywhere from 15-60 seconds so they are pretty lengthy.

Currently I just immediately do the task in the same python process that is running the Flask server, and from testing locally It seems like i can go to the react app in two different browsers and request tasks at the same time and it looks like the raspberry pi is trying to run them in parallel (from what I'm seeing in the printed logs).

What is the best way to allow multiple users to go to the front-end and queue up tasks? When multiple users go to the react app I assume they all connect to the same instance of the back-end. So it it enough just to add a dequeue to the back-end and protect it with a mutex lock (what is the pythonic way to use mutexes?). Or is this too simple? Do I need some other process or method to implement the task queue (such as writing/reading to an external file to act as the queue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the most popular way to run tasks in Python is using [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/). It is a Python framework that runs on a separate process, continuously checking a queue (like Redis or AMQP) for tasks. When it finds one, it executes it, and logs the result to a "result backend" (like a database or Redis again). Then you have the Flask servers just push the tasks to the queue.

In order to notify the users, you could use polling from the React app, which is just requesting an update every 5 seconds until you see from the result backend that the task has completed successfully. As soon as you see that, stop polling and show the user the notification.

You can easily have multiple worker processes run in parallel, if the app would become large enough to need it. In general, you just need to remember to have every process do what it's needed to do: Flask servers should answer web requests, and Celery servers should process tasks. Not the other way around.